# MooTools More Keyboard refreshes page?

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-more

I'm playing around with MooTools, including MooTools More.

I currently have a blank HTML page with a reference to both the core and the more js files. However, when I use `var kb = Keyboard()`, the page gets refreshed. I guess this is not what it is supposed to do.

What is the use of this, or what am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: take a look => http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Keyboard#Keyboard:constructor

Comment: I was very stupid indeed, I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instantiate it with `var kb = new Keyboard();`